# For loop, if statement and Zip python

Tags: python-3.x

```py
a= ["Kiran", "Narut", "Sasue"]
b= ["Kiran", "Naruto", "Sasuke"]
def quality_check(x,y):
    for i,j in zip(x,y):
        if i == j:
            return "Good to go"
        else:
            return "wrong names"
quality_check(a, b)
# Expected: wrong names
# Received: Good to go
```

The code aims to check if the names in the two lists are exactly the same. However, it shows an unexpected result. The results are shown just for the first element of the lists.

Comment: You have to `print` instead of `return`, otherwise the function is done when it returns the first result.

Comment: What is your expected output and your actual output?

Comment: Better to return `True` or `False` instead of two wordy strings for a function like this by the way.

Comment: the expected output is to return "Good to go" if the elements in the first list match elements of second list, index to index.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `return` It will only check for the first elements.

A return statement is used to end the execution of the function, Replace this with `print()` will loop over all the elements.

Comment: I edited the question, please check again

Comment: but print won't work inside the UDF, it has to be return, right?

Comment: what are you trying to do, by adding return it will only compare once as return will end the execution. If you can update the question and add the desired output , we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `quality_check()` is returning after the `if i == j` statement in the first iteration of your `for` loop. That `if` statement is comparing `"Kiran" == "Kiran"` (which is `True`).

Try checking for only 'Wrong names' in the `for` loop. Then return 'Good to go' once the loop completes and no Wrong names have been found.

```py
a = ["Kiran", "Narut","Sasue"]
b = ["Kiran", "Naruto","Sasuke"]
c = ["Kiran", "Narut","Sasue"]

def quality_check(x,y):
  for i,j in zip(x,y):
    if i != j:
      return "Wrong names"
  return "Good to go"

print(quality_check(a,b))
#> Wrong names
print(quality_check(a,c))
#> Good to go
```

Comment: I did the same again. Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should use yield instead of return

```
a= ["Kiran", "Narut","Sasue"]
b= ["Kiran", "Naruto","Sasuke"]

def quality_check(x,y):
    for i,j in zip(x,y):
        if i == j:
            yield "good to go"
        else:
            yield "wrong"
for element in quality_check(a, b):
    print(element)
```

this will return required results
every time you yield from function it returns a iterable object